# How to restrict SSH root login, but allow some exceptions

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, openssh

in openssh,  you can restrict root login (PermitRootLogin no) but can it have an exception?

Comment: But that would mean that root login was permitted ... why not login as a user and then su / sudo?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exception? Either you permit root login or you don't.

Answer (score 7):

Given that logging in as root is not a good idea, have a look at sshd manpage:

> **PermitRootLogin**
>
> Specifies whether root can log in using ssh(1). The
> argument must be ``yes'', ``without-password'',
> ``forced-commands-only'' or ``no''. The default is ``yes''.
>
> If this option is set to ``without-password'' password authenti-
> cation is disabled for root.
>
> If this option is set to ``forced-commands-only'' root login with
> public key authentication will be allowed, but only if the command
> option has been specified (which may be useful for taking remote
> backups even if root login is normally not allowed). All other
> authentication methods are disabled for root.
>
> If this option is set to ``no'' root is not allowed to log in.

So you could use `PermitRootLogin without-password` for allowing private/public key authentication while disallowing password authentication; or maybe `PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only` to let you login as root but without interactive access.

The latter case requires you to edit `authorized_keys` file, to specify which command is enabled for the logging is user, like this:

```
command="rdiff-backup --server" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y... (rest of key)
```

or even better, allow forced-commands-only root login only from specific ip address:

```
from="10.1.1.1",command="/home/user/command/to/execute" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y... (rest of key)
```